# Ansible blockinfile re-print

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am using Ansible's `blockinfile` feature to insert user's public keys into `authorized_keys` file. Keys are stored as variable in `group_vars`.

Inserting works fine, but is there a way to ask `blockinfile` to print blocks from the beginning every time? What I mean is, if I remove one key from variable, and run playbook it still exists in authorized file, because `blockinfile` is only printing once.

Can I make it print whole variable again everytime?

Playbook:

```
- name: Add root authorized keys
  blockinfile:
    state: present
    path: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    block: |
      {{ item.key }} {{ item.label }}
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ item.label }}"
    backup: yes
  with_items: "{{ root_keys }}"
```

This is how variable looks like:

```
root_keys:
- { label: somelabel, key: somekey }
- { label: somelabel2, key: somekey2 }
```

So what I am trying to achieve is that when I remove `somekey2` from `root_keys` variable, it will disappear from `authorized_keys` file.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a native Ansible [`authorized_key`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/authorized_key_module.html) for these operations.

---

As for the question itself if you plan to reorganise `root_keys` in the following way:

```
root_keys:
- { label: somelabel, key: somekey }
- { label: somelabel2 }
```

You can redefine the task to:

```
- name: Add root authorized keys
  blockinfile:
    state: "{{ (item.key is defined ) | ternary('present', 'absent') }}"
    path: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    block: |
      {{ item.key | default(omit) }} {{ item.label }}
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {{ item.label }}"
    backup: yes
  with_items: "{{ root_keys }}"
```

---

If you want to remove the whole element `{ label: somelabel2, key: somekey2 }`, then you should store all possible label-values in a separate list and iterate over that list checking if an element is present in a [`union` or `difference`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) of that all-attributes-list and `root_keys|map(attribute='label')` to determine if a value should be included or not;

<sup>A bad practice-variation would be to parse the file to create this list by parsing the destination file in search for `ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK`. But that, on the other hand would be the only reason you might want to use `blockinfile` instead of `authorized_key` module.</sup>